# Перевод с PascalABC на C++

Tags: c++, pascalabc.net, конвертация, перевод

Искал замены некоторым функциям из PascalABC довольно долго, но так и не нашёл. Проблема в функциях copy, pos и delete. Чем можно их заменить?

```
  for i := 1 to m do
  begin
    readln(s);
    name[i] := copy(s, 1, pos(' ', s)-1);
    delete(s, 1, pos(' ', s));
    val(copy(s, 1, pos(' ', s)-1), min[i], z);
    delete(s, 1, pos(' ', s));
    val(s, max[i], z);
  end;
```

Comment: `string`: `substr`, `find`, `erase`?

Comment: @HarryfromKiev Я пробовал данные функции, но все не мог их правильно подставить.

Comment: Лучше сразу ищите, как сделать split строки по пробелам, поскольку приведённый код делает это, скажем так, не самым оптимальным образом

Comment: Вроде как разобрался, но вот опять проблема с функцией val. Вроде как заменой может послужить atoi, но выдаёт ошибку, что не существует подохдящей функции преобразования, и min[i] "Не является однозначным".